# How to send character sequence to the username and password field within the url through Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I tried to log in in https://login.economicmodeling.com/login/login.php, but the username I put in doesn't show up, and after I run the command to fill in password, it automatically opened a new tab without actually filling in password. Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://login.economicmodeling.com/login/login.php")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("cc-btn cc-dismiss").click()
user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name = user]')
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name = password]')
user.clear()
user.send_keys('xxx')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('xxx')
driver.find_element_by_id("submitbutton").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing single quotes around 'user' and 'password' attributes.

```
user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='user']")
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
```

Sending the form should be done with submit, not click.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("submitbutton").submit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't think this is the problem cause it can acutely find the element. I try to run the code together rather than separate the put in password and user name part and then it works. I think it is some hidden rule of selenium.

Comment: It was tested with Chrome, it works - the user name and password show and it's submitted. I had ignored the line "driver.find_element_by_class_name("cc-btn cc-dismiss").click()" because it's irrelevant, that might be your issue.

Comment: The reason I did that is cause there's a popup requiring me to click 'accept' before I can put in username and password.

Comment: Did you open up the page first with the code, and then run the put in code separately? It is when I run them separately that safari would open up a new tab.

Comment: I ran the code as is with Chrome but without dismissing the cookie terms. I did not get any popup. The cookie acceptance dialog box does not have to be closed, you can freely navigate the site with the dialog being open. Solve one problem first, then add additional functions.

Comment: you know, I guess new tab pop up may only happen in Safari. I ended up run the login code together and there's no problem. If I run the fill in password and username code separately, new window still pops up. Thanks for the information about dialog box!!:)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to login in https://login.economicmodeling.com/login/login.php you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://login.economicmodeling.com/login/login.php")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.fancy.form#userinput"))).send_keys('xxx')
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.fancy.form#passwordinput').send_keys('xxx')
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.submit.button.success#submitbutton").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: emsi]

Comment: I did include the WebDriveWait. It still needs me to run all the lines at once. I can't run the first several lines first and then run the last two lines you have. It will still open up new tab.

Comment: @RosaMa Can please help me to understand `can't run the first several lines first`, `run the last two lines you have` and `still open up new tab` ? We are not opening any new _Tab_ through the code within the solution. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: if I run the first 6 lines first and then run the last 5 lines separately. The browser would open up a new tab.

Comment: user.clear()
user.send_keys('xxx')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('xxx')
These are the lines causing new tab.